# CKeditor stopped working after drush up (6.22 -> 6.25)

Tags: drupal-6, ckeditor

I had I 6.22 drupal site with CKeditor installed/working.  After I used drush up the site itself is working *but* I no longer have that "visual" editor provided by ckeditor.

Any idea of how to get it back running?

Comment: Well, that was easy.   That was a matter of unpacking the contents of the ckeditor downloaded from the ckeditor site (called program) into modules/ckeditor.   

It will add a lot of files into modules/ckeditor/ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was easy. That was a matter of unpacking the contents of the ckeditor downloaded from the ckeditor site (called program) into modules/ckeditor. It will add a lot of files into modules/ckeditor/ckeditor